# Odoo 8 not found module or field

Tags: python, postgresql, odoo

I'm new creating odoo modules so i don't understand something. I'm getting errors something like:

> reference.book.bb module not found

I don't know how works my module: reference.book.aa :D but it works.

Or error like:

> Field medical_id not found

So who can help me? I try all day understand it but... Some code posted below question.

Here what i want:
[image]

**openerp**.py

```
{
   'name': 'AAA',
   'version': '1.0',
   'author': 'LALA',
   'description': '''
     OOO.
     ====================================
   ''',
   'category': 'Website',
   'depends': [
    'base',
    'hr',
    'disable_openerp_online',
    'download_action',
   ],
   'data': [
       'security/security.xml',
       'security/ir.model.access.csv',
       'static/src/xml/view.xml',
       'views/website.xml',
       'views/reference_book.xml',
       'report/report.xml',
   ],
   'installable': True
}
```

**init**.py

```
import controllers
import models
```

models/**init**.py

```
import website
import ambulance_call_form
import res_partner
import reference_book
```

models/reference_book.py

```
from openerp import models, fields, api

class referenceBookView(models.Model):
    _name = 'reference.book.aa'

    mdeical_id = fields.Integer(string="ID")
    mdeical_name = fields.Char(string="Name")
```

views/reference_book.xml

```
<openerp>
<data>
    <!-- Medical List START -->
    <record model="ir.ui.view" id="view_reference_book_form">
        <field name="name">Reference book</field>
        <field name="model">reference.book.aa</field>
        <field name="view_type">tree</field>
        <field name="view_mode">tree,form</field>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <tree string="Reference book tree">
                <field name="mdeical_id" />
            </tree>
        </field>
    </record>
    <record model="ir.actions.act_window" id="action_medication_list">
        <field name="name">Medication list</field>
        <field name="res_model">reference.book.aa</field>
        <field name="view_type">tree</field>
        <field name="view_mode">form,tree</field>
        <field name='view_id' ref='view_reference_book_form'/>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <tree string="Medication list tree">

            </tree>
        </field>
    </record>
    <record model="ir.actions.act_window" id="action_medication_list">
        <field name="name">Medication list</field>
        <field name="res_model">reference.book.aa</field>
        <field name="view_type">form</field>
        <field name="view_mode">form,tree</field>
        <field name='view_id' ref='view_reference_book_form'/>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <form string="Medication list form">

            </form>
        </field>
    </record>
    <!-- Medical List END -->

    <!-- Heart Rythm List Start -->
    <record model="ir.ui.view" id="view_heart_rythm_tree">
        <field name="name">Heart rhythm disturbances</field>
        <field name="model">reference.book.aa</field>
        <field name="view_type">tree</field>
        <field name="view_mode">tree,form</field>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <tree string="Heart rhythm disturbances tree">

            </tree>
        </field>
    </record>
    <record model="ir.actions.act_window" id="action_heart_rythm_disturbations_list">
        <field name="name">Heart rhythm disturbances list</field>
        <field name="res_model">reference.book.aa</field>
        <field name="view_type">tree</field>
        <field name="view_mode">form,tree</field>
        <field name='view_id' ref='view_heart_rythm_tree'/>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <tree string="Medication list tree">

            </tree>
        </field>
    </record> 
    <record model="ir.actions.act_window" id="action_heart_rythm_disturbations_list">
        <field name="name">Heart rhythm disturbances list</field>
        <field name="res_model">reference.book.aa</field>
        <field name="view_type">form</field>
        <field name="view_mode">form,tree</field>
        <field name='view_id' ref='view_heart_rythm_tree'/>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <form string="Heart rhythm disturbances form">

            </form>
        </field>
    </record> 
    <!-- Heart Rythm List End -->

    <!-- ST Segment List Start -->
    <record model="ir.ui.view" id="view_st_segment_tree">
        <field name="name">ST segment of changes in evaluation</field>
        <field name="model">reference.book.aa</field>
        <field name="view_type">tree</field>
        <field name="view_mode">tree,form</field>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <tree string="ST segment of changes in evaluation tree">

            </tree>
        </field>
    </record>
    <record model="ir.actions.act_window" id="action_st_segment_list">
        <field name="name">ST segment of changes in evaluation list</field>
        <field name="res_model">reference.book.aa</field>
        <field name="view_type">tree</field>
        <field name="view_mode">form,tree</field>
        <field name='view_id' ref='view_st_segment_tree'/>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <tree string="ST segment of changes in evaluation tree">

            </tree>
        </field>
    </record> 
    <record model="ir.actions.act_window" id="action_st_segment_list">
        <field name="name">ST segment of changes in evaluation list</field>
        <field name="res_model">reference.book.aa</field>
        <field name="view_type">form</field>
        <field name="view_mode">form,tree</field>
        <field name='view_id' ref='view_st_segment_tree'/>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <form string="ST segment of changes in evaluation form">

            </form>
        </field>
    </record> 
    <!-- ST Segment List End -->

    <!-- Status List Start -->
    <record model="ir.ui.view" id="view_status_tree">
        <field name="name">Status</field>
        <field name="model">reference.book.aa</field>
        <field name="view_type">tree</field>
        <field name="view_mode">tree,form</field>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <tree string="Status tree">

            </tree>
        </field>
    </record>
    <record model="ir.actions.act_window" id="action_status_list">
        <field name="name">Status list</field>
        <field name="res_model">reference.book.aa</field>
        <field name="view_type">tree</field>
        <field name="view_mode">form,tree</field>
        <field name='view_id' ref='view_status_tree'/>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <tree string="Status tree">

            </tree>
        </field>
    </record>
    <record model="ir.actions.act_window" id="action_status_list">
        <field name="name">Status list</field>
        <field name="res_model">reference.book.aa</field>
        <field name="view_type">form</field>
        <field name="view_mode">form,tree</field>
        <field name='view_id' ref='view_status_tree'/>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <form string="Status form">

            </form>
        </field>
    </record>
    <!-- Status List End -->

    <!-- Pharmaceutical Administration List Start -->
    <record model="ir.ui.view" id="view_pharmaceutical_administration_tree">
        <field name="name">Pharmaceutical administration</field>
        <field name="model">reference.book.aa</field>
        <field name="view_type">tree</field>
        <field name="view_mode">tree,form</field>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <tree string="Pharmaceutical administration tree">

            </tree>
        </field>
    </record>
    <record model="ir.actions.act_window" id="action_pharmaceutical_administration_list">
        <field name="name">Pharmaceutical administration list</field>
        <field name="res_model">reference.book.aa</field>
        <field name="view_type">tree</field>
        <field name="view_mode">form,tree</field>
        <field name='view_id' ref='view_pharmaceutical_administration_tree'/>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <tree string="Pharmaceutical administration tree">

            </tree>
        </field>
    </record>
    <record model="ir.actions.act_window" id="action_pharmaceutical_administration_list">
        <field name="name">Pharmaceutical administration list</field>
        <field name="res_model">reference.book.aa</field>
        <field name="view_type">form</field>
        <field name="view_mode">form,tree</field>
        <field name='view_id' ref='view_pharmaceutical_administration_tree'/>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <form string="Pharmaceutical administration form">

            </form>
        </field>
    </record>
    <!-- Pharmaceutical Administration List End -->

    <!-- Product Use Intensity List Start -->
    <record model="ir.ui.view" id="view_product_intensity_tree">
        <field name="name">Product use intensity</field>
        <field name="model">reference.book.aa</field>
        <field name="view_type">tree</field>
        <field name="view_mode">tree,form</field>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <tree string="Product use intensity tree">

            </tree>
        </field>
    </record>
    <record model="ir.actions.act_window" id="action_product_use_intensity_list">
        <field name="name">Product use intensity list</field>
        <field name="res_model">reference.book.aa</field>
        <field name="view_type">tree</field>
        <field name="view_mode">form,tree</field>
        <field name='view_id' ref='view_product_intensity_tree'/>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <tree string="Product use intensity tree">

            </tree>
        </field>
    </record>
    <record model="ir.actions.act_window" id="action_product_use_intensity_list">
        <field name="name">Product use intensity list</field>
        <field name="res_model">reference.book.aa</field>
        <field name="view_type">form</field>
        <field name="view_mode">form,tree</field>
        <field name='view_id' ref='view_product_intensity_tree'/>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <form string="Product use intensity form">

            </form>
        </field>
    </record>
    <!-- Product Use Intensity List End -->

    <!-- Procedures List Start -->
    <record model="ir.ui.view" id="view_procedures_tree">
        <field name="name">Procedures</field>
        <field name="model">reference.book.aa</field>
        <field name="view_type">tree</field>
        <field name="view_mode">tree,form</field>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <tree string="Procedures tree">

            </tree>
        </field>
    </record>
    <record model="ir.actions.act_window" id="action_procedures_list">
        <field name="name">Procedures list</field>
        <field name="res_model">reference.book.aa</field>
        <field name="view_type">tree</field>
        <field name="view_mode">form,tree</field>
        <field name='view_id' ref='view_procedures_tree'/>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <tree string="Procedures tree">

            </tree>
        </field>
    </record>
    <record model="ir.actions.act_window" id="action_procedures_list">
        <field name="name">Procedures list</field>
        <field name="res_model">reference.book.aa</field>
        <field name="view_type">form</field>
        <field name="view_mode">form,tree</field>
        <field name='view_id' ref='view_procedures_tree'/>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <form string="Procedures form">

            </form>
        </field>
    </record>
    <!-- Procedures List End -->

    <!-- Pain Scale List Start -->
    <record model="ir.ui.view" id="view_pain_scale_tree">
        <field name="name">Pain scale</field>
        <field name="model">reference.book.aa</field>
        <field name="view_type">tree</field>
        <field name="view_mode">tree,form</field>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <tree string="Pain scale tree">

            </tree>
        </field>
    </record>
    <record model="ir.actions.act_window" id="action_pain_scale_list">
        <field name="name">Pain scale list</field>
        <field name="res_model">reference.book.aa</field>
        <field name="view_type">tree</field>
        <field name="view_mode">form,tree</field>
        <field name='view_id' ref='view_pain_scale_tree'/>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <tree string="Pain scale tree">

            </tree>
        </field>
    </record>
    <record model="ir.actions.act_window" id="action_pain_scale_list">
        <field name="name">Pain scale list</field>
        <field name="res_model">reference.book.aa</field>
        <field name="view_type">form</field>
        <field name="view_mode">form,tree</field>
        <field name='view_id' ref='view_pain_scale_tree'/>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <form string="Pain scale tree">

            </form>
        </field>
    </record>
    <!-- Pain Scale List End -->

    <!-- Menu Start -->
    <menuitem id="menu_reference_book" name="Reference book" sequence="500" />
        <menuitem id="menu_medical_list" name="Reference book Lists" parent="menu_reference_book" sequence="500" />
            <menuitem id="menu_medication_list" action="action_medication_list" parent="menu_medical_list" sequence="500"/>
            <menuitem id="menu_heart_rythm_disturbations_list" action="action_heart_rythm_disturbations_list" parent="menu_medical_list" sequence="501"/>
            <menuitem id="menu_segment_of_changes_in_evaluation" action="action_st_segment_list" parent="menu_medical_list" sequence="502"/>
            <menuitem id="menu_status_list" action="action_status_list" parent="menu_medical_list" sequence="503"/>
            <menuitem id="menu_pharmaceutical_administration_list" action="action_pharmaceutical_administration_list" parent="menu_medical_list" sequence="504"/>
            <menuitem id="menu_product_use_intensity_list" action="action_product_use_intensity_list" parent="menu_medical_list" sequence="505"/>
            <menuitem id="menu_procedures_list" action="action_procedures_list" parent="menu_medical_list" sequence="506"/>
            <menuitem id="menu_pain_scale_list" action="action_pain_scale_list" parent="menu_medical_list" sequence="507"/>
    <!-- Menu End -->
</data>
```

Errors:

```
ParseError: "ValidateError
Field(s) `arch` failed against a constraint: Invalid view definition

Error details:
Field `mdeical_id` does not exist

Error context:
       View `Reference book`
[view_id: 510, xml_id: n/a, model: reference.book.aa, parent_id: n/a]" while parsing file:///C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Odoo%208.0-20151013/server/openerp/addons/gmps/views/reference_book.xml:12, near
        <record model="ir.ui.view" id="view_reference_book_form">
            <field name="name">Reference book</field>
            <field name="model">reference.book.aa</field>
            <field name="view_type">tree</field>
            <field name="view_mode">tree,form</field>
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
                <tree string="Reference book tree">
                    <field name="mdeical_id"/>
                </tree>
            </field>
        </record>
```

Or with module is same.

Comment: Hi can you please add more description of your problem ? Did you restart the server ? Have you placed everything according to module structure as given in the **guidelines** ?

Comment: I edited with image what i want. When i insert <field name="res_model">reference.book.blabla</field> when i get error reference.book.blabla module not found and same with field... And how i can make new module or field ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution for that. When Installed module first time i create table reference.book.aa and Odoo somewhere store a cache. So when i tried to update or uninstall and when install odoo use that cache. And thinks if cache exists so i can get data from where and do not found my next time created table reference.book.bb . So i uninstalled module copied to addons folder and renamed with different name. It fixed it. But i thinks somewhere i can remove that cache.

Answer (score 1):

According to new api you should update your code as follow,

```
from openerp import models, fields, api

class ReferenceBookAa(models.Model):
    _name = 'reference.book.aa'

    #### Define fields here
    medical_id = fields.Integer('ID')
```

For your reference

[Odoo new API guideline](http://odoo-new-api-guide-line.readthedocs.org/en/latest/fields.html)

[Odoo documentation](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/8.0/reference/orm.html)

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem here is of the ***indentation***.(Four spaces in any block)

Put everything as PEP8 standards as shown above by Empiro Technologies Pvt.

```
from openerp import api, fields, models

class ReferenceBookAa(models.Model):
    _name = 'reference.book.aa'

    #### Define fields here
    medical_id = fields.Integer('ID')
```